# Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: org.apache.lucene.document.FieldType.setIndexed when indexing pdf files error

Tags: pdf, indexing, lucene, pdfbox

im trying to index pdf files in lucene 6.6.0 and pdfbox 2.0.7
im getting some following errors. (EDITED)

```
run:
    Indexing ke folder: 'D:\Kuliah\rancangan document indexing\dir-index\'...
    Indexing PDF document: D:\Kuliah\rancangan document indexing\dir-pdf\dua.pdf
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at tigasepuluh.Playground.indexDocs(Playground.java:110)
        at tigasepuluh.Playground.indexDocs(Playground.java:88)
        at tigasepuluh.Playground.main(Playground.java:65)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: org.apache.lucene.document.FieldType.setIndexed
        at org.apache.pdfbox.examples.lucene.LucenePDFDocument.<clinit>(LucenePDFDocument.java:123)
        ... 3 more
    C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
    BUILD FAILED (total time: 5 seconds)
```

And this is github link to my complete code

[my complete code](https://github.com/ridho-pratama-putra/TigaSepuluh/blob/master/src/tigasepuluh/Playground.java)

Comment: Please post the code and error messages as text.

Comment: thanks for your response. sorry for that.

Comment: re the question you asked in DM (about LucenePDFDocument.java) - yes, copy it in the src directory. However you'll have to adjust the package declaration / or move the file, obviously. Netbeans will suggest what to do.

Comment: so pdfbox will be a package right? am i should to test & compile package too?

Comment: PDFBox is in jar files. The easiest is to use pdfbox-app-2.0.7.jar. However this does not contain the example code, i.e. LucenePDFDocument.java. (And you need IndexPDFFiles.java too). Btw always use "@Tilman Hausherr", this way I get a ping on my mobile and a notification in the browser.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr sorry, iam new user :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line in your copy of org.apache.pdfbox.examples.lucene.LucenePDFDocument:

```
TYPE_STORED_NOT_INDEXED.setIndexed(false);
```

to

```
TYPE_STORED_NOT_INDEXED.setIndexOptions(IndexOptions.NONE);
```

The problem you had is because the PDFBox example was made for lucene 4.